# What happens when/if onReceive override called from several apps?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

For instance some example here, a phone running 2 or more apps, calling `onReceive()`.
Has android some kind of task order to run all thouse @Overrides by ordered sequence? Probably yes, then in which order, app importance?

App1 & App2:

App1:

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};
```

App2:

```
  private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    deleteMessageFromInbox(message); // or just something that can conflict other Instance
  }
};
```

Comment: Haha, thx for the edit Cœur, it amazing that no one has seen that misspelling before and i got a solution answer for this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the order that intents are handled using the [android:priority](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html#priority) attribute of `BroadcastReceivers`. When an intent can be handled by multiple receivers, Android generates an ordered list (based on the priority of each receiver) and delivers the intent sequentially.

So in your case, when you register the receivers (via `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)`, all you have to do is assign a higher priority (via a call to `setPriority(int priority)`) to the intent filter in App1 than to the filter in App2 to make sure that App1 receives the intent before App2.

There is also an old [article in the Android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html) that gives you examples about how to implement this mechanism efficiently.